# C# / EF Best practice for constantly checking a value in the DB?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

So basically I want a method that when called will keep checking the db until a certain value exists. The record is updated in an external way (not in this application).

I wasn't sure the best practice around this. Should it be something like below?

```
while (true) 
{
 using(DbContext context = new myDBContext())
 { 
    if (context.whateverimlookingfor.exists())
       return;
 }
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
}
```

Comment: this is called polling and it's the traditional way of doing this. I guess now we have some better way, such as establish a socket connection between the server and client (requiring some access right to the server)...

Comment: If you need to do this, you can use `SqlDependency`. But that is a code smell. The anti-pattern you are using is called "IPC over RDBMS", it is a personal pet hate of mine. The correct way to fix this is to architecture your systems to not pass information across databases.